# How to get different results from a random.choice in a nested while loop

Tags: python, random, nested-loops

This is a rock, paper scissors program minigame, however the random.choice selects only one from the list even though it repeats the choice in a nested loop.

I've tried looking at other answers but most of them state about using a loop, the others aren't adequate enough for my case.

```
              rpsloop = True
              while rpsloop:
                  #credit to https://thehelloworldprogram.com/python/python-game-rock-paper-scissors/ for help
                  aiselc = ["rock","paper","scissors"]
                  computer = random.choice(aiselc)
                  print("type exit to leave")
                  player = input("rock, paper, scissors?")
                  if player == computer:
                    print("Tie!")
                    print("-------------------------")
                    continue
                  elif player == "rock":
                    if computer == "paper":
                     print("You lose!", computer, "covers", player)
                     print("-------------------------")

                     continue
                    else:
                     print("You win!", player, "smashes", computer)
                     print("-------------------------")
                     continue
                  elif player == "Paper":
                    if computer == "Scissors":
                     print("You lose!", computer, "cut", player)
                     print("-------------------------")
                     continue
                    else:
                     print("You win!", player, "covers", computer)
                     continue
                  elif player == "Scissors":
                    if computer == "Rock":
                     print("You lose...", computer, "smashes", player)
                     print("-------------------------")
                     continue
                    else:
                     print("You win!", player, "cut", computer)
                     print("-------------------------")
                     continue
                  else:
                       break
          else:
              break
```

I expect the computer to pick either rock, paper or scissors.
it picks one and keeps the value even after a loop.
however it picks another value each execution.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that using `==` in Python when comparing strings does an **exact** comparison.  This means that the case of the letters is taken into account when comparing strings.  For example, `Scissors` and `scissors` would be considered not equal to each other.

I highly suspect that you are putting in all of your choices in lowercase.  This means that if you were to enter `scissors` or `paper`, your `if` statements for checking if the player entered `Scissors` would not execute.  What will end up happening is that your loop will exit as what you put in is not handled by any of the other `if` statements due to the case-sensitive nature of the string comparison.  This is why `rock` only executes and none of the other `if` statements do.

Specifically, take note that in your `if` statements, `rock` is lowercase, but `Scissors` and `Paper` have their first letters capitalized.

Therefore, given this implementation change your `if` statements so that the strings are in fact lowercase.

```
elif player == "paper":
     if computer == "scissors":
...
...

elif player == "scissors":
    if computer == "rock":
...
...
```